# VSTO plugin automacally disable when runing on no debug mode

Tags: vsto

I'm developing a vsto outlook plugin and works perfectly when I run on debug mode. If I install it, it's always disabled automacally and I can't make it work.
Does anybody knows what's happening or could I do to figure out what's the problem?

Comment: You are the only one who can possibly figure it out - you can shill run your addin under the debugger even if you build in the Release mode - if you enable all managed code exceptions in the VS debugger, it will stop on each exception.

Answer (score 0):

We have encountered times when our Chem4Word add in has been hard disabled. This may have caused by pressing the stop button in visual studio during debugging! This makes word think the add in has crashed.  In our case it was only apparent when trying to run it as an installed add in, running in visual studio IDE never showed an issue.

See here for instructions on how to clear any hard disabled add ins
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-re-enable-a-vsto-add-in-that-has-been-disabled?view=vs-2019

I think that this applies to all versions of office.
You can also look in the registry at

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\Resiliency\DisabledItems

Substitute your target application and version number as appropriate.
The key should not have any items if nothing in hard disabled.